# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP encountered when using spring

Tags: java, spring, exception, maven, spring-mvc

I am new to spring. I am trying to use spring mvc to build a small web.
When I start the project, I get:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 22 in the generated java file
The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

Stacktrace:
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:314)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:589)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Http status is 500, but my index.jsp just have

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

In the web.xml:

```
 <servlet>
   <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
 <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

the action-servlet.xml:

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.Controller"/>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix"><value>/jsp/</value></property>
    <property name="suffix"><value>.jsp</value></property>
</bean>
```

I put index.jsp under ***src/main/webapp/jsp/*** folder.
Could anyone please give me some hint about this problem and the problems in my xml files.I am new to spring, so lot's of confusion.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks there's some version mismatch. Make sure servlet-api and jsp-api are *not* included in your `WEB-INF/lib` folder

If using Maven, you must set these dependencies to `<scope>provided</scope>` so that they are not included in the artifact (target/foo.war)

If using eclipse, you should install another plugin - m2e-wtp, which takes care of `<provided>` scope dependencies (m2e doesn't do it when synchronizing with WTP)

Comment: Thank you for reminding, but I don't have a lib folder under WEB-INF now. I am using maven build, so all jars are in maven lib.

Comment: @Xuanzi Han that's some information you should've specified ;) see my update

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue because I used

```
 - jdk1.7.0_45
 - apache-tomcat-8.0.18
```

But after I change the server to

```
 - apache-tomcat-7.0.57
```

It was fixed.